# How to get if an Infragistic unboundDataCheckbox is checked in WebGridData WebForms ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, webforms, infragistics, webdatagrid

I can't believe that after more than 3 hours of searching I haven't found any clear reference to how to obtain and modify the status of an Infragistic checkbox in a WebForms WebGridData, ASP.NET, I have tried everything, but it doesn't work, it would very helpful if someone could point me to some of this, greetings

Comment: Can you expand your question to include some code you have tried?

Comment: Hello, i have change my code, i'm doing something else, but thanks, have a nice day.